# SOLR results too broad including not matching

Tags: solr

I have a DB where i store strings of hex colors like `f9f8f7` or `aaaaaa`

If search for a color, strange things happen:

1. if i search `aaaaaa` i get the one and only result hat contains  `aaaaaa`
2. but if I search `f9f8f7` i get more results not pertinent...

it seems like since `f9f8f7` ha letters and numbers together Solr tries to split and search for single letters..

how do i prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

You define your field to *not* split on numbers inside words. You can use the [WhitespaceTokenizer](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/tokenizers.html) in your field definition instead of the one you're currently using. The whitespace tokenizer will only break words on whitespace instead of using a range of other splitting points (which will depend on your tokenizer or if you have a WordDelimiter(Graph)Filter active in your analysis chain.

You can test out exactly how your strings are being processed for a specific field by going to "Analysis" under the collection / core in your Solr Admin.

Comment: the problem is that the search is searching in other textfield like names etc... so how do i limit the search only in a specific field?

Comment: The `qf` parameter is usually used to tell Solr which fields to search in, or by prefixing the query with the field name (`field:foo`)